# R packages with open data in them

Tags: data-request, programming

I love and play a lot with the Baseball data package for R (Lahman), and I was wonder if there is anything like it but for more oriented to social sciences. Either surveys or admin data (PSID, HRS, ARF, NLSY, ACS) would be great.

I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a human-friendly [list of all 731 datasets in R](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html), as well as CSV download links.

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

(1) Check out the [WebTechnologies Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html), which contains a bunch of packages linking to (potentially) open data on the web. In most cases, these packages will give you a list or data.frame structure you can work with.

(2) Take a quick glance through [the list of CRAN packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html), some of which are data-only or at least contain small datasets for their examples. For example, Hadley Wickham has some data only packages ([fueleconomy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fueleconomy/index.html), and [hflights](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hflights/index.html)) but neither are strictly social science. [HistData](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistData/index.html) has datasets used in famous visualizations. [pdfetch](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdfetch/index.html) can retrieve economic time-series. Etc. etc.

Comment: Also worth calling out the (standard) `datasets` package, the `acs` package, and the `Zelig` package.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [mlbench package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=mlbench): "A collection of artificial and real-world machine learning benchmark problems, including, e.g., several data sets from the UCI repository."

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out [RSocrata](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RSocrata/) which lets you list and download any public dataset from governments throughout the country that leverage Socrata for their Open Data Portals.