# Open datasets for data mining R

Tags: data-request, programming

Are there any (big) datasets for datamining in R considering that I want to build a sort of expert system application with practical usage? The domains may be: health data, lifestyle etc

Comment: Have you looked at [R packages with open data in them](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3631/70)? Another good starting point might be [Publicly available datasets](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/155/5164) over at Data Science SE.

Comment: What is "big" ?

Answer (score 4):

R itself has a datasets package. Check out the **[R Datasets Package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/00Index.html)**

> Description: Base R datasets
>
> Details: This package contains a variety of datasets. For a complete list, use library(help = "datasets").

([details](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/datasets-package.html))

---

**Update:** Thanks to @PatrickHoefler for pointing out the [full list of easily imported R datasets](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html).

Comment: The *datasets* package is actually just one of many [R packages with open data in them](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3631/70).